# Ayuda con NullPointerException en jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un combo que muestra una lista de un catalogo que esta en la base de datos

```html
<h:outputText value="#{datospersonalesmsgs['datospersonales.descuento.title']}:" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="catBeneficio" value="#{DatosPersonalesComponent.solicitudeses.sysBeneficios.idSysBeneficio}" required="false" valueChangeListener="#{DatosPersonalesComponent.obtenerDescuento}">
  <p:ajax event="change" update="catBeneficio,dialogBeneficio,dialogDiscapacidad, dialogAgricola" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{SysBeneficiosComponent.listSysBeneficioss()}" var="descuentos" itemValue="#{descuentos.idSysBeneficio}" itemLabel="#{descuentos.descripcion}">
  </f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Y  manda a llamar a un metodo con el Valuelistener, lo que quiero que haga es que si en el combo se selecciono la opcion 5 o 10 que es el  id del catalogo, el boleano sea true y me mande un dialogo dependiendo la opcion, ese dialogo lo estoy llamando en el ajax con el update, pero me manda NullPointer en el if y no se por que es?

```
 public void obtenerDescuento(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("ENTRA A OBTENER DESCUENTO");

    if (solicitudeses.getSysBeneficios() != null) {

        if (solicitudeses.getSysBeneficios().getIdSysBeneficio().equals(5)) {
            System.out.println("ES PERSONA CON DISCAPACIDAD");
            msjdiscapacitado = true;

        }
        if (solicitudeses.getSysBeneficios().getIdSysBeneficio().equals(10)) {
            System.out.println("ES TRABAJADOR AGRICOLA");
            msjtrabajadoraagricola = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tengo unas preguntas, en que if te manda el NullPointer? en vez del != null, utiliza un <> "" en sysBeneficios.IdSysBeneficios para que no caiga en null.

Answer (score 0):

Si en donde esta saliendo la excepción es:

```
if (solicitudeses.getSysBeneficios() != null) { //NullPointerException
}
```

Debe ser porque `solicitudeses` es un objeto que no estas inicializando en tu componente antes de usarlo. Ya que ahí estarías haciendo:

```
null.getSysBeneficios()
```

Y `null` no es un objeto que posea ese método por eso la excepción. Primero valida que `solicitudeses` no sea `null` antes de tratar de acceder a sus métodos.

```
if (solicitudeses != null) {
    if (solicitudeses.getSysBeneficios() != null) {
    }
}
```

Comment: me sigue marcando el nullPointer, en mi Component tengo un metodo init y tengo lo siguieente                                                                 
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {   
        solicitudeses = new Solicitudes();
      solicitudeses.setSysVigencias(new SysVigencias());     }                         es correcto?